# Can MATLAB plot a time-event bar?

Tags: matlab, plot, time

[image: time example image]

The closest I got is plotting points after translating the categorical data into numeric data:

```
plot(time, data,'LineStyle','none', 'Marker', '.')
```

Comment: You'd probably get a better response if you supplied some sample data.

Comment: If your sole aim is to generate this graphic (not present these events as the inputs/context for a mathematical analysis), then I believe using MATLAB to do so is overkill - use Excel to generate a one-row Gantt Chart (which looks the same as what you've shown). If you want to generate a one-row Gantt chart in MATLAB, follow [this guy's answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/371898-plotting-a-gantt-chart-from-a-matrix).